# Setting a div's height to auto is not adjusting with content

Tags: html, css

I am unsure what I am doing wrong, but no matter what I try, I cannot get my `#service-brief-message` container to adjust its height based on the content.

I added `display: block` and even gave it padding to try and help, but it didn't resolve it.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
#red, #blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
} 
#service-brief-message {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#service-brief-message-container {
  color: #2a2a2a;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
</div>
<div id="service-brief-message">
  <div id="service-brief-message-container">
    <h1 class="section-title">CUSTOM TAILORED WEBSITE DESIGN SOLUTIONS</h1>
    <h3 class="section-description" id="service-brief-description">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the absolute positioning on the `#service-brief-message-container` to just be the following does the trick:

```
#service-brief-message {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#service-brief-message-container {
  color: #2a2a2a;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### **I believe this is what you are trying to achieve(?): https://jsfiddle.net/2cdjrqg9/**

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware `position:absolute` would hinder this.

Comment: No worries @Paul - Let me know if you need any other help

Answer (score 0):

In the `#service-brief-message`, get rid of the:

```
padding: 20px 0;
```

If you want to add a padding, add the following to your CSS:

```
.section-description{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `position: abosolute` use `relative`.
Absolute positioning will take the element out of the normal flow, and will not contribute to the size of the parent.

```css
#red, #blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
} 
#service-brief-message {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#service-brief-message-container {
  color: #2a2a2a;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;/*absolute;*/
  width: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
</div>
<div id="service-brief-message">
  <div id="service-brief-message-container">
    <h1 class="section-title">CUSTOM TAILORED WEBSITE DESIGN SOLUTIONS</h1>
    <h3 class="section-description" id="service-brief-description">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
</div>
```